# Docker on a server: --mount type=bind or -v?

Tags: docker, server

I've been trying to run a nextflow pipeline with a Docker image I've created on a server. I've tested this pipeline on my local client and it works fine but trying to run it on a server (ArchLinux, docker version 18.09.6) gives me many different errors. The problem is that the pipeline requires a huge database (NCBI:nt ~120GB) as an "input" (just read, not modify it). On the local client, I've used the `temp` flag for nextflow, which is equivalent to `--mount type=volume,src=<src_path>,target=/tmp` flag. This works perfectly on the local client. Once I've uploaded it to the server, I get different problems. I've been accessing the server using ssh (Window'sPowerShell and wsl2). I've tried using the following options:

Using `--mount type=bind,src=<src_path>,target=/output`:

I get the following error:
`docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: <src_path>/.` The same occurs if many different flags (e.g. `readonly`) or different propagation forms are used.

Using `-v <src_path>:/output`: A different error is given:
`docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '<src_path>': mkdir /share/library: permission denied.`. I find this error quite unusual since my user does has the permissions to create files and directories in the src-path. Is there any way of forcing docker to use the permissions of my user?

Is `--mount` or `-v` even the right way of accessing this database from within the container? Any help or idea is always welcome since nothing I've found seems to bring me forward...

EDIT:

Rather than a "nextflow" question, it is more of a docker question, since running `docker run <any_option_mentioned_above> <img_name>`
returns the same errors.

Comment: what is your OS ? are you sudo ? if run docker with sudo does it work ?

Comment: The OS in the server is ArchLinux. I do not have the permissions for running as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup I've used to run nextflow processes inside docker containers:

main:

```
process mount_example {
label 'dockerised'
input:
file foo from bar

containerOptions "-v /path/to/source:/path/to/target/inside/docker/"

script:
"""
ls /path/to/target/inside/docker/
"""
}
```

and in config:

```
docker {
enabled = true
registry = 'yourdockerregister'
}
process {
withLabel: dockerised 
{
container: yourdockerregistry
}
}
```

Comment: This is the same as I've already posted with runOptions ```-v <src_path>:/output```. It returns the given error above.

Comment: Does creating a docker container with those mount options work when you do it manually on the server, without using nextflow?

Comment: So then the issue is not nextflow, but your docker setup. Can you change the permissions of the folder you are trying to mount so that whatever user your docker is running as has permission to write in that folder?

Comment: Exactly, the problem is the setup for docker. Sorry for the confusion. Sadly, I am also not able to change the permissions of the folder. How can I see the permissions my "docker" has? There is a group in the server called ```docker``` and this group has the permissions to modify the src-path (eg.``` sg docker -c 'touch <srcpath>/test.txt'``` ). Shouldn't this suffice? Or should the user within the created container also need such permissions?

Answer (score 0):

One of the features of a host mount that docker provides is it will create the folder if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise, when doing a bind mount in Linux, which is what this option is doing:

```
--mount type=bind,src=<src_path>,target=/output
```

Linux will not create the directory for you and the mount command will fail. To resolve you can switch back to a host mount, or create the directory in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly here with "switch back to a host mount". And I don't understand your argument since the src_path does exist!

Comment: @MWP a volume where the source is a path is a host mount. So you wouldn't change bind to volume in your command. The error message is indicating that the path you provided doesn't exist.